# Programming and data structures

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Suggest a data structure for representing a subset S of integers from 1 to n. Following operations on the set S are to be performed in constant time (independent of cardinality of S).
You may assume that the data structure has been suitable initialized.

(i). MEMBER (X):

Check whether X is in the set S or not

(ii). FIND-ONE(S):  If S is not empty, return one element of the set S (any arbitrary element will do)

(iii). ADD (X): Add integer X to set S

(iv). DELETE (X):   Delete integer X from S.

My analysis:-
I think hash table will work fine here ,but how will hash table work for FIND-ONES(S) operation.Because i might need to scan the entire has table to look for the present element.

Comment: What is SS? Is it the same as S?

Comment: It was typo ,i have corrected it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a regular hashset for this in java. In the case of the `FIND-ONE(S)` what you would do is, call `isEmpty()`. If that returns false, use the built in iterator, and just get the first value the iterator returns.

Answer (score 1):

A hash table would work, but you need to think about the specific implementation. If you use the [compact version from Python 3.6](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-December/123028.html), you can perform `FIND-ONEs` in constant time by inspecting the `entries` list.

> For example, the dictionary:
>
> ```
> d = {'timmy': 'red', 'barry': 'green', 'guido': 'blue'}
> ```

is represented as follows:

> ```
> indices =  [None, 1, None, None, None, 0, None, 2]
> entries =  [[-9092791511155847987, 'timmy', 'red'],
>             [-8522787127447073495, 'barry', 'green'],
>             [-6480567542315338377, 'guido', 'blue']]
> ```